# pycsw and GeoNode — how to import metadata?

Tags: import, metadata, geonode, pycsw

I am using pycsw as part of GeoNode 2.4.  I need to transfer metadata from an old app, which is powered by GeoNode 1.2 and GeoNetwork, but I can't find pycsw-admin.py file, which is supposed to import metadata.

Is this file named differently under GeoNode or is there some other way to import metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://geonode.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/admin/migrate).  `pycsw-admin.py` is not used for GeoNode specific workflows.  Having said this, pycsw connects directly to the GeoNode core database to generate metadata.

Comment: I was trying to avoid clonning of our old app for running _geonode syncdb_, but it seems to be the only way. Thank You, Tom.